# Button interaction in a DataGrid column template

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, buttonclick

In a C# WPF program I have a grid that I have successfully populated with my data. One column has a button that I want to link to an edit page. The code is below.

```
var col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
col.Header = "Edit";
var template = new DataTemplate();
var textBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
textBlockFactory.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding("rumId"));
textBlockFactory.SetBinding(Button.NameProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding("rumId"));
textBlockFactory.AddHandler( Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((o, e) => System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("TEST")));
template.VisualTree = textBlockFactory;
col.CellTemplate = template;
template = new System.Windows.DataTemplate();
var comboBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
template.VisualTree = comboBoxFactory;
col.CellEditingTemplate = template;
dgData.Columns.Add(col);
```

The code successfully runs and I get a message box every time I choose a button.

How can I get this to call another method and then retrieve from this the row number of the button that I chose?

The subsequent method would look something like, how can I call it?

```
void ButtonClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("hi Edit Click 1");
// get the data from the row
string s = myRumList.getRumById(rumid).getNotes();
// do something with s
}
```

Comment: I would rather use other control than the DataGrid in order to have more flexibility. I have done something using rows and buttons with a ListBox, data template and a little bit of code-behind. I can guive you some expample if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the `Id`, or better yet the entire data object, as the `CommandParameter`

```
void ButtonClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi Edit Click 1");

    Button b = sender as Button;

    // Get either the ID of the record, or the actual record to edit 
    // from b.CommandParameter and do something with it
}
```

This will also work if you decide to switch your application so it uses the MVVM design pattern. For example, the XAML would look like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
```

Comment: It does not get as far as calling ButtonClick that is where I am stuck.

Comment: @RogerStark Just change your line of code which sets the `Click` event so it points to your method instead of being defined inline: `textBlockFactory.AddHandler( Button.ClickEvent, ButtonClick);`

Comment: Thanks, that worked so far, now I need to extract the id +  sender {System.Windows.Controls.Button: 5} object {System.Windows.Controls.Button} I want to extract the '5'

Comment: @RogerStark Cast your `sender` into a `Button` like I have in my answer, then get the `5` from either `Button.Content`, `Button.DataContext`, or `Button.CommandParameter`. I would suggest using `Button.CommandParameter`, but that means you have to set that binding when the button is first created: `textBlockFactory.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding("rumId"));`

Comment: Resolved, appreciate the help, I have only been programming c# for 2 weeks so I an a real newbee.

Comment: @RogerStark Glad you got that sorted out :) If you find a question or answer on this site that is helpful, please click the up arrow next to it. If the answer is to a question you asked and you wish to mark it as the accepted answer, click the Check Mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you need to have the `rumId` of the clicked Text block in order to edit it.

While setting the `Click` event you can do the following.

```
textBlockFactory.AddHandler( Button.ClickEvent, 
     new RoutedEventHandler((o, e) => 
      {
         var thisTextBlock = (TextBlock) o; // casting the sender as TextBlock 
         var rumID = int.Parse(thisTextBlock.Name); // since you bind the name of the text block to rumID
         Edit(rumID); // this method where you can do the editting 
      }));
```